# What would happen to a submarine coated in water repellent

Tags: water, material-science

I saw the article about laser-etched hydrophobic metal, and it got me thinking, how would a submarine function differently if coated as such? Would it move faster, sink completely, be unable to move at all, ..?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't hurt to think a little more carefully.  Why would you expect something with positive buoyancy to sink regardless of its surface energy?  Why do you think a high effective surface energy will improve (or degrade) the submarine's interaction with local flow and turbulence?

Comment: I'm just lost on how a complete loss of friction would affect a submarine. I thought maybe it would "slip" between the water particles, like a person jumping in one of those ball pits.

Comment: The *physics* content here is not the submarine, but how how laser-etched hydrophobic metals behave differently (dynamically) when submerged than metals that are not treated in this manner. With the presence of the submarine in the question, it feels too much like engineering.

Comment: Really I'm wondering whether buoyancy is affected in the case of a sealed envelope as a result of the hydrophobic nature of the outside of the envelope. It seems like, all other things constant, something would have to change. It would at least travel through the water faster I'd think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the etched material is hydrophobic because of entrapped air in the etchings therefore, the water doesn't touch most of the surface.   This means that when submersed, it will eventually loose it's hydrophobic properties as the air dissipates into the water.   The submarine would also have the problem of increasing water pressure with depth which compresses the entrapped air as well as increase the rate at which the air would dissolve into the water.    You would have to find a way of generating more gas molecules such as having enough velocity for supercavitation, somehow induce electrolysis along the surface, have a slow chemical reaction producing gases or somehow bleed additional air to the surface through pores.   Also keep in mind that the current methods of laser etching the metal is hard pressed to produce one square inch.